# Cannot SSH into server from one particular computer (connection closed/did not receive auth string)

Tags: networking, server, ssh

I'm having trouble using ssh to access a server that I recently set up with 16.04, but only from a specific computer (my laptop).  When I run `ssh -vvv -p sshPort user@host`, I get this output:

```
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4, OpenSSL 1.0.2g-fips  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/user/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/user/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: /home/user/.ssh/config line 35: Applying options for host
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "host" port xxxx
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to host [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] port xxxx.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa type 1                                                                                                                                        
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory                                                                                                                                            
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1                                                                                                                                  
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory                                                                                                                                            
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1                                                                                                                                       
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory                                                                                                                                            
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1                                                                                                                                  
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory                                                                                                                                            
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1                                                                                                                                     
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory                                                                                                                                            
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1                                                                                                                                
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory                                                                                                                                            
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1                                                                                                                                   
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory                                                                                                                                            
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1                                                                                                                              
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

On the server side, `/var/log/auth.log` just has the entry:

```
Apr 28 18:50:49 host sshd[2618]: Did not receive identification string from yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy
```

So far, I haven't been able to figure out why this is happening, and I'm open to suggestions.  A few things I've ruled out:

**Not port forwarding/firewall configuration issues**: I'm able to log in to this host from a remote VPS, so access from the WAN is working properly.  I can also ssh in from another host on the same LAN.

**Not an issue with fail2ban/denyhosts**: This is a new install that doesn't yet have auto-ban software configured.  `/etc/hosts.deny` and `/etc/hosts.allow` are both empty.  SSH config is the default that ships with 16.04.

**Not the SSH agent**: I can ssh into other hosts from my laptop with agent forwarding and from there SSH into the host I'm having trouble with.

I did recently install kvm and bridge-utils on the laptop.  I've seen some mentions of bridge-utils possibly being an issue here, but I doubt it, since ssh works fine with other hosts.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: it looks like some filtering on the network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this issue.  Though I'm still unsure of the root cause, it appears that changing the port forwarded by my router has solved the problem.  It's possible that the port I was on was already in use by another forwarding rule, or reserved for use by the router.